# Performance issue with generating Excel with groupby and sum of the groupby records

Tags: c#, excel, performance, .net-core, closedxml

In C# using closedXML, I inserted tables with groupby records and after every groupby result Included an extra line to do sum of all the records. Issue here is for upto 2k records performance is okay but for records more then 7k its taking 1.5minutes to create an Excel. Could anyone please suggest me for a scalable code?
Do we have any other way to sum of specific columns which has less impact on performance.
Suggestions are highly appreciated.

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add();
worksheet.ShowGridLines = false;
var dataList = dataSet.ToList();  //dataList retuns groupby response
if (dataList.Any())
{
    var row = 3;
    int column = 1;
    var includeHeader = true;
    DataTable headers = GetColumnHeaders();
    worksheet.Cell(1, column).InsertTable(headers);// to include custom headers
    row = row + 2;
    foreach (var data in dataList)
    {
        var accName = (string)data.GetType().GetProperty("accountName").GetValue(data);
        var dataModel = ((IEnumerable<object>)data.GetType().GetProperty("expList").GetValue(data)).ToList();
        worksheet.Cell(row - 1, column).SetValue($"Billed To:{accName}").Style.Font.SetBold().Font.SetFontColor(XLColor.Black);
        worksheet.Cell(row, column).InsertTable(dataModel).SetShowHeaderRow(false).SetShowColumnStripes(false);
        int sumFrom, sumTo = 0;
        sumFrom = row;
        row = row + dataModel.Count + 1;
        sumTo = row - 1;
        worksheet.Row(row).Style.Font.SetBold().Font.SetFontColor(XLColor.Black);
        worksheet.Cell(row, column).SetValue($"Total For: {accName}");
        worksheet.Cell(row, 24).FormulaA1 = "SUM(X" + sumFrom + ":X" + sumTo + ")";
        worksheet.Cell(row, 25).FormulaA1 = "SUM(Y" + sumFrom + ":Y" + sumTo + ")";
        worksheet.Cell(row, 26).FormulaA1 = "SUM(Z" + sumFrom + ":Z" + sumTo + ")";
        worksheet.Cell(row, 27).FormulaA1 = "SUM(AA" + sumFrom + ":AA" + sumTo + ")";

        row = row + 2;
    }
}
```